# Index Creation after Load Data InFile

Tags: mysql, indexing, bulkinsert

I'm using MySQL v5.6.

I'm inserting about 10 millions rows in a newly created table (InnoDB). I try to choose the best way to do this between "Load Data InFile" and multiple inserts.

Load Data InFile should be (and is) more efficient, but I'm observing a weird thing: the index creation is much more longer (by 15%) when using "load data infile"...

Step to observe that (each step starts when the previous is all done):

1. I create a new table (table_1)
2. I create a new table (table_2)
3. I insert 10 millions rows in table_1 with multiple insert (batches of 5000)
4. I insert 10 millions rows in table_2 with load data infile
5. I create 4 indexes at a time (with alter Table) on table_1
6. I create 4 indexes at a time (with alter Table) on table_2 -> about 15% more longer than the previous step

What could explain that?

*(Of course, results are the same with steps ordered 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5.)*

Comment: Good.  You eliminated several variables by changing step order, etc.  More questions:  Were the records in the same order?  Was the `PRIMARY KEY` already established?  `AUTO_INCREMENT` or natural?  If Natural, were the records in that order?  One ALTER with 4 ADD INDEX clauses?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the data load with INSERT resulted in more data pages left occupying the buffer pool. When creating the indexes on the table that used LOAD DATA, it first had to load pages from disk into the buffer pool, and then index the data in them.

You can test this by querying after you load data:

```
SELECT table_name, index_name, COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE
WHERE table_name IN ('`mydatabase`.`table_1`', '`mydatabase`.`table_2`')
GROUP BY table_name, index_name;
```

Then do this again after you build your indexes.

(Of course replace `mydatabase` with the name of the database you create these tables in.)

Comment: This could really be the reason why! However, INNODB_BUFFER_POOL doesn't seem to exist in INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Did you misspelled it? Ref here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-i_s-tables.html

Comment: Sorry! Yes, I misspelled it. It's really INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE. I will edit the above to correct this.

Comment: For more info, try `SELECT count(*), sum(number_records) as rows, sum(data_size), min(data_size), round(avg(data_size)) as avg, max(data_size), index_name FROM ... GROUP BY index_name;`